# How to scrape paginated table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all the data from the table on this website (https://report.boonecountymo.org/mrcjava/servlet/SH01_MP.I00290s) but can't seem to figure out how I would go about scraping all of the subsequent pages. This is the code to scrape the first page of results into a CSV file:

```
import csv

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.showmeboone.com/sheriff/JailResidents/JailResidents.asp'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

fileList = []

# For the table-header cells
tableHeader = soup.find('tr', attrs={'class': 'table-header'})
rowList = []
for cell in tableHeader.findAll('th'):
    cellText = cell.text.replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '')
    rowList.append(cellText)
fileList.append(rowList)

# For the table body cells
table = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'class': 'stripe'})
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    rowList = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        cellText = cell.text.replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '')

        if cellText == "Details":
            continue

        rowList.append(cellText)

    fileList.append(rowList)

outfile = open("./prison-inmates.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerows(fileList)
```

How do I get to the next page of results?

Code taken from this tutorial (http://first-web-scraper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Really there are only two ways.  Mimic a button press on the page, and rescrape the table, or figure out the ajax call to the backend data, and see if you can just get it from the underlying api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I wasn't able to get your posted code to run, I did find that the original [tutorial](http://first-web-scraper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) code you linked to, can be changed on the `url =` line to:

```python
url = 'https://report.boonecountymo.org/mrcjava/servlet/SH01_MP.I00290s' \
    + '?max_rows=250'
```

Running `python scrape.py` then successfully outputs `inmates.csv` with all available records.

In short, this works by:

- instead of: `How do I get to the next page` ?
- we pursue: `How do I remove pagination` ?
- we cause the page to send all records at once so there would be no pagination to deal with in the first place
- This allows us to use the original tutorial code to save the complete set of records.

### Explanation

- `url = 'https://report.boonecountymo.org/mrcjava/servlet/SH01_MP.I00290s'` to use the new URL. The old URL in the tutorial: `http://www.showmeboone.com/sheriff/JailResidents/JailResidents.asp` redirects to this new URL, but doesn't work with our solution so we can't use the old URL
- `\` is a line break allowing me to continue the line of code on the next line, for readability
- `+` is to concatenate so we can add the `?max_rows=250`.
- So the result is equivalent to `url = 'https://report.boonecountymo.org/mrcjava/servlet/SH01_MP.I00290s?max_rows=250'`
- `?max_rows=<number-of-records-to-display>` is a query string I found that works for this particular `Current Detainees` page. This can be found by first noticing the `Page Size` text entry field meant for users to set a custom rows per page. It shows a default value `50`. Examine its HTML code, for example in Firefox browser (52.7.3), use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to show the Firefox's Web Developer `Inspector` tool window. Click the [Select element button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/UI_Tour#Select_element_button) (icon resembles a box outline with a mouse cursor arrow on it), then click on the input field containing `50`. HTML pane below reveals via highlight: `<input class="mrcinput" name="max_rows" size="3" title="max_rowsp" value="50" type="text">`. This means it submits a form variable named `max_rows`, which is a number, default `50`. Some web pages, depending on how it is coded, can recognize such variables if appended to the URL as a query string, so it is possible to try this by appending `?max_rows=` plus a number of your choice. At the time I started the page said `250 Total Items` , so I chose to try the custom number `250` by changing my browser address bar to load: `https://report.boonecountymo.org/mrcjava/servlet/SH01_MP.I00290s?max_rows=250`. It successfully displayed 250 records, making it unnecessary to paginate, so this `?max_rows=250` is what we use to form the URL used by our script
- Now however the page now says `242 Total Items`, so it seems they are removing inmates, or at least inmate records listed. You can: `?max_rows=242`, but `?max_rows=250` will still work because `250` is larger than the total number of records `242`, and as long as it is larger the page will not need to paginate, and thus allow you to have all the records on one page.

### Warranty

- This isn't a universal solution for scraping table data when encountering pagination. It works for this `Current Detainees` page and pages that may have been coded in the same way
- This is because pagination isn't universally implemented, so any code or solution would depend on how the page implements pagination. Here we use `?max_rows=...`. However another website, even if they have adjustable per-page limits, may use a different name for this `max_rows` variable, or ignore query strings altogether and so our solution may not work on a different website
- Scalability issues: If you are in a situation with a different website where you need millions of records for example, a download-all-at-once approach like this can run into perhaps memory limits both on the server side and also on your computer, both could time out and fail to finish delivering or processing. A different approach, resembling something like pagination that you had originally asked for, would definitely be more suitable

So in the future if you need to download large amounts of records, this download-all-at-once approach will likely run you into memory-related trouble, but for scraping this particular `Current Detainees` page, it will get the job done.